# Compiling failed: argument type 'Character' does not conform to expected type 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this code:

```
private func validate(text: String) -> String {
    let acceptableChar: Set<Character> = ["0", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "."]
//    let acceptableChar: [Character] = ["0", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "."]

    var clearText = text
    clearText.removeAll(where: { !acceptableChar.contains($0) })
    return clearText
}
```

that work fine in `Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)` in every device (iPhone, iPad and Mac), but in `PreviewProvider`, I have this error:

```
    Compiling failed: argument type 'Character' does not conform to expected type 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'
.....


    error: argument type 'Character' does not conform to expected type 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral'
        let acceptableChar: Set<Character> = [__designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[0].[0].value", fallback: "0"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[1].[0].value", fallback: "9"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[2].[0].value", fallback: "8"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[3].[0].value", fallback: "7"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[4].[0].value", fallback: "6"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[5].[0].value", fallback: "5"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[6].[0].value", fallback: "4"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[7].[0].value", fallback: "3"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[8].[0].value", fallback: "2"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[9].[0].value", fallback: "1"), __designTimeString("#2775.[2].[0].value.[10].[0].value", fallback: ".")]
```

Anyone know how to modify the `private func validate(text: String) -> String {` to eliminate this error?

Comment: Why not use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset ?

Comment: I tried with CharacterSet, but was unable to get it to work.
Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @CesarePiersigilli why don't you use filter? `func validate(text: String) -> String { text.filter  { "0"..."9" ~= $0 || "." == $0 } }`

Comment: Your solution also works well. I have update my func in this mode: private func validate(text: String) -> String {
    let filterText = text.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 || "." == $0 }
    return filterText
}

Comment: See https://nshipster.com/characterset/

Comment: @Alexander - Reinstate Monica Unfortunately, I was unable to find a working solution with your suggestion.

Comment: @CesarePiersigilli What went wrong? The "validating user input" section looks like *precisely* what you're looking for: https://nshipster.com/characterset/#validating-user-input

Comment: @Alexander - Reinstate Monica You can show me an example, as has made Leo Dabus or Asperi?

Comment: I'm on mobile, so i can't compile it, but I did my best to get it roughly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following declaration

```
let acceptableChar = Set<Character>(arrayLiteral: 
     "0", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", ".")
```

*Tested & worked with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2*

Answer (score 1):

I did a small hack that made it work in Xcode Previews

```swift
extension Character: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    public init(stringLiteral value: StringLiteralType) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CharacterSet`

```
import Foundation

func filter(_ input: String) -> String {
    var allowed = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    allowed.insert(".")
    return String(input.unicodeScalars.filter { allowed.contains($0) })
}

print(filter("a123123b123152345.1j123412340"))
```

Comment: Your solution, in PreviewProvider, get this error: "Compiling failed: argument type 'Unicode.Scalar' does not conform to expected type 'ExpressibleByStringLiteral' ". Have you a solution to this error?

Comment: @CesarePiersigilli Hmmm, nope. Compiles fine for me under `Apple Swift version 5.1.3 (swiftlang-1100.0.282.1 clang-1100.0.33.15)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0`

Comment: The problem is when I test your code in a Switfui view in PreviewProvider (Editor -> Canvas (Alt + Command + Enter)). This problem has been resolved by 'Asperi' and 'Leo Dabus' code.

Comment: I don't have the time to set up a test bench to replicate the issue, sorry. But that's odd. Does this also cause a compiler error? `let x: UnicodeScalar = "x"`

Comment: Yes. Work only for compile un app. For example let acceptableChar: Set<Character> = ["0", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", "."] don't work in PreviewProvider, while let acceptableChar = Set<Character>(arrayLiteral: 
     "0", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1", ".") work fine.

Comment: Another example that works well in Swiftui Preview Provider is `func validate(text: String) -> String { text.filter { "0"..."9" ~= $0 || "." == $0 } }`

Comment: I think something is up here. The code in your original post `let chars: Set<Char> = ["1", "2", ...]` is valid code, exhibiting a similar issue to this. `Set` conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`, and `Character` conforms to `ExpressibleByExtendedGraphemeClusterLiteral`, so they should be happy with initialization like that. Similarly, UnicodeScalar` should conform to `ExpressibleByUnicodeScalarLiteral`, which should enable initialization via `" "` syntax.  Could you make a bug report for this?

Comment: Can I ask a question about StackOverflow or should I do another way?

Comment: Hmm? I don't understand your question/comment

Comment: You wrote me: `Could you make a bug report for this?`. What should I do? Your solution seems interesting to me and therefore I would like someone to make it work.

Comment: "Could you make a bug report for this?. What should I do? " ... I think you should make a bug report on this... that's why I asked you to make a bug report. I don't see where the confusion is. https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **SwiftUI** this is an simple solution:

```
yourString.split(separator: Character(" "))
```

> Tested and worked with Xcode 11.5